# fprintf results in a utf-16 text file when lines are over 100 characters long

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am trying to learn how to work with files in C, the goal of this code is to write an amount of small case letters specified by the user to a text file regenerated each time the program is run. This is done in visual studio community 2019 in case that matters.

What I am struggling with is that if I put more than 100 characters on the same line (aka user inputs a number greater than 49) the resulting .txt file is encoded in utf-16 rather than utf-8, which is why I added two newlines every 50 iterations of the for loop.

Say I need to write more than 100 characters on each row for whatever reason without putting them in just one string, is there a workaround? Why is it happening in the first place?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>

int main() {
    char* file = "test.txt";
    FILE* fp = fopen(file, "w");
    int Min = 97;
    int Max = 122;

    int i, n, newline = 1;

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("%s : couldn't be created", file);
    }
    else printf("%s : created successfully\n", file);

    printf("How many characters do you want to generate? : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        char letter = rand() % (Max + 1 - Min) + Min;
        fprintf(fp, "%c ",(char )letter);
        if (i == newline*50) {
            fprintf(fp, "\n\n");
            newline++;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you determining that the file is somehow UTF-16? I generated 5000 characters several times and the file is perfectly fine for me using both the exact code above as well as without printing any newlines..

Comment: @RetiredNinja have you ran it without the if (i == newline*50) part that prints newlines? that was a workaround.
 if I run it without that the file is gibberish such as ⁰⁨ⁱ⁧⁨⁵⁭⁥⁡⁹⁬⁮⁬⁦⁤⁸⁦⁩⁲⁣⁶⁳⁣⁸⁧⁧⁢⁷⁫⁦⁮ⁱ and with notepad I can see the encoding being UTF-16 LE in the bottom right part of the window

Comment: As I said, I ran it both with and without the code that prints the newlines generating 5,000 characters. I also generated 50,000 characters with the line breaks at 500 characters. Windows Notepad is terrible at recognizing files. You should try Notepad++.

Comment: You are right, when opening the files with other editors like words, notepad++ or wordpad the writing does indeed look correct. Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts

Comment: Thanks a lot.

I'm new to stackoverflow but I don't believe I can mark the question as solved and your answer as correct unless you answer the question rather than commenting, correct?

Comment: I would say so, since the problem is the same notepad bug